# WPF: How can I find the source of an inherited property value

Tags: wpf, inheritance, padding

I've been working on a WPF-project that has a certain nick that I can't seem to grasp: there are a couple of controls that include other controls and are styled by a Style-definition in a Resource Dictionary. One of the inner controls is a Label. That Label has an inherited Padding of 5.

The Label has no styling defined, let alone any padding. And it's indicated to be inherited, but I can't find where that Padding is coming from. So, my question is: how can I figure out where this value is inherited from?

Comment: You need to to know from what `Style` (for example - key) element inherited value?

Comment: Yep, anything that will point me in the direction of where the Padding is coming from. I already found out with `ValueSource vals = DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(this.ButtonCloseAllDocuments, PaddingProperty);` that the BaseValueSource is Style. But I have more than one style ... ;-)

Comment: I would like to offer you the same solution 8). And if you can for example edit the styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michiel M said 
DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource is the way to go.

There is a distinct order of evaluation where the value can originate:

Most important is on top

1. Forced Value by Property System (CoerceValueCallback)
2. Animation
3. Locally set value
4. Style trigger
5. Template trigger
6. Style setter
7. Theme style trigger
8. Theme style setter
9. Inheritance
10. Default value

Finally ValidateValueCallback accepts or discards the value if set

This probably helps

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for your reply. I know that this is the order of evaluation, more or less. However, what I would like to know is if there's a function (maybe GetValueSource) to determine where exactly in this stack the value is set. Preferably which Animation, Trigger, Style, Theme Style etc. exactly.

Comment: Well GetValueSource returns a ValueSource and it has a property BaseValueSource http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.basevaluesource.aspx which will tell you where it comes from. This is the closest you will get to the location without implementing own handling of iterating all possible sources looking for the DependencyProperty you need.