# How do I determine where a XAML object property value coming from?

Tags: wpf

I have a bunch of textblock objects in my program, and the foreground color of all of these is white.  I want to find out what causes it to be this way.

Is there any means in Visual Studio of tracing back the origin of a property value, whether by template or containing object?

EDIT:
After issuing a bounty, this question got a lot of interesting responses with a variety of proposed approaches.  I think there's something there, but so far I have not been able to figure out how to apply any of these more effectively than just trial and error hunting through the code.  If anybody wants to take up the charge and advance one of the responses as useful, I'm watching.

Comment: It is a long time ago I used XAML (Silverlight times), but I remember when I opened up the view in the designer or with Blend, that I could see where it got the properties from. Did you try any of these yet? Have a look for Blend here: http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/

Comment: I opened Blend for Visual Studio 2013 and loaded the solution, and opened a XAML file.  I see the current value for control properties but not why it has those values.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu  May be this is usefull  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/24/introducing-the-ui-debugging-tools-for-xaml.aspx

Comment: VisualStudio 2015 has the tech!  Good to know.  Not useful for VS2013 though.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to poke around the visual tree when I need to understand where bound values are coming from.  You can use it to look at your control properties and follow either bindings back to DataContexts or walk up and down the tree to see where a value might be inherited from.

Fire up Snoop, drag the crosshairs over your WPF application (or refresh the process list and select from the dropdown), then position your mouse pointer over your TextBlock control and Ctrl-Shift-LeftClick.  Snoop will zoom the visual tree in on your control and allow you to look at or edit your control properties.

Comment: I have looked with snoop, and all I find is foreground=#FFFFFFF, inherited.  Walking up the tree it continues to say that until it switches to #FF000000, inherited.  I was stuck.  Randomly I changed templates to various colors, and found <Style x:Key="SubTabStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"><Setter Property="Plum"/> to be effective in changing the white.  But I fail to see how Snoop helps me here.  TabItem is not represented in the tree.

Comment: It seems to depend unfortunately on how your styles are getting bound to your controls, ie. whether they're specified explicitly on your control or a parent, or whether they're bound by type in a resource dictionary (either yours or one that you inherit because it's for a base type - probably TabItem from the sound of it).  Finding the Style property and seeing whether it's explicitly set works in some cases.  Alternatively, Delve or DelveBinding can be helpful in some cases (from right-clicking  Style in properties).

Comment: Also the other blocker can be when your styles are being set on something which is being applied as part of a DataTemplate, then it's outside the navigable Visual Tree and I've had little luck with visualization tools there & end up resorting to trial and error changes typically to resolve issues.  This answer might give you a starting point though : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722269/wpf-how-can-i-find-the-source-of-an-inherited-property-value  - See Samuel's comment right at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

There is already an answer showing a managed tool.

Here I'm expanding my comment about debugging the InitializeComponent.
Let's assume a basic xaml as a proof of concept.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Border  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="10,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="199"> 
        <TextBlock Name="analysethis" Text = "why is it blue?" TextWrapping="Wrap" />    
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Intercepting the event of the `Foreground` Property of the `TextBlock` is difficult because we can't subclass `TextBlock` (otherwise the style will be lost)
and we can't override a `Freezable`. Should I have no other solutions, I would set a breakpoint on the following converter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Color), typeof(String))]
    public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is Color)) return null; // << BP here
            var result = value.ToString();
            return result;
        }
```

linking it to the `TextBlock` with a static resource

```
        <TextBlock Name="analysethis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,81,0,75"
                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
               Path=Foreground.Color, Converter={StaticResource ColConv} }" >
```

After starting the Debug, one can see the initial default `Foreground` assigned to `"#FF000000"` and the starting condition is in the stack

```
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx) + 0xc6 byte   
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx) + 0x37 byte
```

Then there is a second hit on the breakpoint and the source of the actual Foreground color can be finally found in the stack

```
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fce, System.Windows.Style oldStyle, System.Windows.Style newStyle) + 0xcd byte 
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) + 0x757 byte    
+       newEntry    {System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry}    System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
+       _value  {System.Windows.Style}  object {System.Windows.Style}
+       _value  {#FF0000FF} object {System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush}
+       _targetType {System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateStyleProperty() + 0x63 byte
```

Please note, if you are interested, in a further effort the PropertyIndex shown above (linked to the `Foreground DependencyProperty`) could be traced back to the:
`BamlSchemaContext`, a Non-Public Member of the `xamlReader` in the `WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml`, that contains the `System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo.LineNumber`

Edit

Here is a starting draft of how to automate the stack trace analysis

[ValueConversion(typeof(Color), typeof(String))]
    [Serializable]
    public class SolidBrushToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {

```
protected MethodInfo EffectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod
{
    get
    {
        if (effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod == null)
        {
            var effectiveValueEntryType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(t => t.Name == "EffectiveValueEntry").FirstOrDefault();
            if (effectiveValueEntryType == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            var effectiveValueEntryValuePropertyInfo = effectiveValueEntryType.GetProperty("Value", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (effectiveValueEntryValuePropertyInfo == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod = effectiveValueEntryValuePropertyInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
            if (effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

        }
        return effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod;
    }
}

protected MethodInfo EffectiveValuesGetMethod
{
    get
    {
        if (effectiveValuesGetMethod == null)
        {
            var dependencyObjectType = typeof(DependencyObject);
            var effectiveValuesPropertyInfo = dependencyObjectType.GetProperty("EffectiveValues", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (effectiveValuesPropertyInfo == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            effectiveValuesGetMethod = effectiveValuesPropertyInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
            if (effectiveValuesGetMethod == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return effectiveValuesGetMethod;
    }
}

#region Private fields
private MethodInfo effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod;
private MethodInfo effectiveValuesGetMethod;
#endregion

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!(value is Color)) return null;
    var result = value.ToString();
    if (result.Equals("#FF0000FF")) {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        foreach (StackFrame frame in st.GetFrames()) {
                if (frame.GetMethod().Name.Equals( "UpdateEffectiveValue" )) {
                    foreach (ParameterInfo info in frame.GetMethod().GetParameters()) {
                        Debug.WriteLine ("parameter name " + info.Name
                                         + ", type " + info.ParameterType.ToString());
                        if (info.Name.Equals("newEntry")) {
                            object newEntry = info.GetRealObject(new StreamingContext()); //SET BreakPoint HERE! (to be continued ...)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

here is the view of the Property found from the VS Debugger
[image]

Comment: This looks very interesting.  I got lost at that last Call stack.  I would have no clue how to interpret that and understand what the source was.  I'm also unclear on how that PropertyIndex traceback would work.

Comment: Very interesting start.  Looks worthy of a Code Project article.

Comment: This seems really complicated. I'd think Visual Studio should just provide something like F12 functionality to take you directly to the source of the value.

Answer (score 2):

### You could use [DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper.getvaluesource.aspx) method.

[DependencyPropertyHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper.aspx) is a static class and here is an example how you can use it:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Foreground="Red" Loaded="OnWindowLoaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>     
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Foreground="Green"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetValueSource(this.textBlock1);
            SetValueSource(this.textBlock2);
            SetValueSource(this.textBlock3);
        }

        private static void SetValueSource(TextBlock textBlock)
        {
            textBlock.Text = DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(textBlock, TextBlock.ForegroundProperty).BaseValueSource.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output of WPF example application]

Comment: How and where?  I don't have a DependencyPropertyHelper object, that I know of.

Comment: Can DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource be used at design time?

Answer (score 1):

WPF inspector has ability to trace styles:
https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/, see Style tracing section. Is that what are you looking for?

Comment: This looks useful.  I will check it out.  I'm open to other approaches besides.  Edit: darn. not compat with wpf 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written a common style for text block in the Resource dictionary

Just try overriding the style by

```
  <TextBlock.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Resources>
```

Comment: In fact I set the style on a TabItem.  This had the effect of setting TextBlock color on both the tab header and the tab page, when I only wished to set one.  Setting a single Textblock style is going to affect both also, and is no better.  (Also, this doesn't answer how I would track down the offending line.)